# Apache NiFi Integration Log

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-ec2, apache-nifi

Due to business needs, AWS nodejs or Java logs are now sent to Apache NiFi (version 1.23.2) via http. In NiFi, it is hoped that the logs can be automatically integrated and written to a file. When the file is written When the data is larger than 100MB, the log file will be compressed and sent to AWS S3, and then continue to be written to another file with a unique file name, and so on. How to implement this in Apache NiFi (version 1.23.2), my NiFi Service is created in AWS EC2

Python sends test log code:

```
import requests
import os

nifi_url = 'http://ip address:8080/logs'

directory_path = '/Users/arz/Desktop/logs/'

file_list = os.listdir(directory_path)

for file_name in file_list:
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.strip()
                response = requests.post(nifi_url, data=line)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    print(f'Successfully sent line from {file_name}: {line}')
                else:
                    print(f'Failed to send line from {file_name}: {line}')
                    print(f'Response status code: {response.status_code}')
                print(f'Response content: {response.text}')
    else:
        print(f'Skipping directory: {file_name}')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your heap can spare the ~100 MB (which I would think it can), the general approach is to receive the files perhaps with `HandleHttpRequest` then send them to a `MergeContent` or `MergeRecord` processor with a Minimum Size of 100MB and a Maximum Size of, say, 101 MB (this is a soft limit). When the incoming files have accumulated in the Merge processor until they reach the size limit, then the merged FlowFile will be transferred downstream. At that point you can use `CompressContent` into `PutS3Object`. I believe the FlowFile coming out of the Merge processor will have a unique filename attribute, but if it doesn't you can use `UpdateAttribute` to set the filename to something unique (perhaps using Expression Language functions like `now():toNumber()` or `UUID()`) before the `PutS3Object`.

If you use `HandleHttpRequest` to receive the incoming log files, don't forget to include a `HandleHttpResponse` somewhere in the flow so the client will know the request has finished processing. If they want to "set it and forget it", you can put the `HandleHttpResponse` right after the `HandleHttpRequest` and it will immediately return a status code. Otherwise you put `HandleHttpResponse` in the appropriate point of the flow. Don't put it after the Merge processor because if the same client is sending multiple log files, it won't get a response for the first request so it won't send another.

Comment: Use Python to send the content (text) in the test log file to Apache NiFi line by line, but the log content received by the ListenHTTP processor cannot be merged in the MergeContent processor. The Python code is as above

Comment: Why can't it be merged?

Comment: There are about 300,000 pieces of log data in the test log. After sending it to Apache NiFi using Python, the MergeContent processor cannot merge it according to the total size of the data stream. I hope to merge it again when the total size of the data stream reaches 100MB, but In the MergeContent processor, now only merging is performed based on 'Minimum Number of Entries' and 'Maximum Number of Entries'

Comment: If you set the Min and Max Number of Entries to something ridiculous (like the value of MAX_INT or something) and Min and Max Group Size to 100 and 101 MB respectively, then it will merge when Min Group Size is satisfied (i.e. when the total size reaches 100 MB) and will never hit Min Number of Entries. You may need to set Min and Max Bin Age to something really high as well (like 1-2 days), or maybe try setting all those unwanted properties to zero so they'll be ignored :shrug: Set Max Number of Bins to 1 (or 2 if 1 fails, there was a bug with 1 but I think it was fixed)